# Array from object in nested class

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, nested

I'm about to make a class about parsing, here's part of my code.

```
public class Parsing {

   //some other atributes here

   public class Pack {
       String type;
       int[] brand;
       int total;
   }

   Pack[] v = new Pack[25];    

   public void setpackType(int a, String b) {
       v[a].type = b;
   }

   public String getpackType(int a) {
       return v[a].type;
   }

   public int getpackTotal(int a) {
       return v[a].total;
   }

   public void setpackTotal(int a, int b) {
       v[a].total = b;
   }

   public void setpackBrand(int a, int b, int c) {
       v[a].brand[b] = c;
   }
```

and

```
   public final void process(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
       Scanner scanner;
       scanner = new Scanner(new File(s));
       try {
           if (scanner.hasNext()) {
               int y = scanner.nextInt();
               int i = 1;
               while (i <= y) {
                   v[i] = new Pack();
                   setpackType(i, scanner.next());
                   setpackTotal(i, scanner.nextInt();
                   int k = 0;
                   while (k < hh) {
                       setpackBrand(i, k, scanner.nextInt());
                   k++;
                   }
                   i++;
               }
           }
       } finally{
           scanner.close();
       }
   }
}
```

It's compiled with no error but when I tried to run, I got this:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Parsing.setpackTotal(Parsing.java:112)
    at Parsing.process(Parsing.java:153)
    at Parsing.main(Parsing.java:202)
```

I already tested it line by line. `setpackType` works just fine!

But I don't understand why `setpackTotal` AND `setpackBrand` can't work.

Thank you so much for help :)

Comment: If `i` runs beyond 24 (the last index in `v`) you will get this exception. What is the value of `y` in `process()`?

Comment: If `v` is not null, then `a` must be different between the `setpackTotal` and `setpackType` calls. Add `System.out.println` calls to see the values, or debug through the code.

Comment: After reformatting your code - the `i++` statement should be inside the while block. But that doesn't explain the NPE, here we have an infinite loop.

Comment: BTW - as the code you've shown, doesn't compile, it's hard to tell, if the problem is inside this draft/fragment or in the real code that we haven't seen yet...

Comment: y is 4. i++ actually is inside the while block. The whole code is pretty long, I can't put it here, I think :/ but it's compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Java are zero indexed, try changing your `i` variable in your `process` method to begin from `0` instead:

```
int i = 0;
while ( ... ) { 
   ...
   i++;
}
```

Comment: I changed it but there was not any different. But thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring that is missing a `)` here:

```
setpackTotal(i, scanner.nextInt();
```

The `NullPointerException` can be caused because of the `scanner.nextInt()`.

Try to debug the `scanner` to solve the problem.

Also, [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9464718/1064325) resolves part of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change `setpackTotal()` to:

```
public void setpackTotal(int a, int b) {
    v[a] = new Pack();
    v[a].total=b;
}
```

Comment: he **is** doing this: `v[i]=new Pack();`. it would override the current instance!